# How to access the laptops camera from Google Colab for object detection in live streaming video?

Tags: deep-learning, video-streaming, google-colaboratory

I am trying to detect mask on a live video using Google Colab. ALthough i can use the camera to capture images but not to stream a live video. How can that be done?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. Since colab is running in a browser, you need to give proper permissions for the site to access webcam
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi

Since the video is a sequence of image, you can save the images with mask detected as a video file.